# Extra argument 'error' in call, not fixing

Tags: ios, swift

This error is not getting fixed. Please help me out.

```
@IBAction func LoginButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let email = UserName.text
    let password = PasswordField.text

    if(password!.isEmpty || email!.isEmpty) {
        return
    }

    let myurl = NSURL(string:"some url")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myurl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let poststring = "email=\(email)&password=\(password)"
    request.HTTPBody = poststring.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        var err : NSError!
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = json {
            var resultValue:String = parseJSON["status"] as String
            print("result: \(resultValue)")
            if (resultValue=="success") {
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

I know to add this piece of code to get rectify, but I am new to iOS Swift 2.0. Don't know how to handle it.

```
do {
    if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
        print(jsonResult)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Can any one help me out to add this line of code to rectify my error problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Don't care about error then Just replace

```
var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
```

with this:

```
var json = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
```

or your code will be:

```
@IBAction func LoginButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let email = ""
    let password = ""

    if(password.isEmpty || email.isEmpty) {

        return
    }

    let myurl = NSURL(string:"some url")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myurl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let poststring = "email=\(email)&password=\(password)"
    request.HTTPBody = poststring.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        do {
            if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

                let resultValue:String = json["status"] as! String
                print("result: \(resultValue)")
                if (resultValue=="success")
                {
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}
```